# WhatsApp does not proceed and stuck at "initialising"

Tags: internet, whatsapp-messenger

**Whatsapp is/was down, see [@wa_status](https://mobile.twitter.com/wa_status) for updates**

Something has got my WhatsApp stuck at "Initializing" stage!

After some time it says "could not complete the initialization process. Check if Internet is connected!"

The phone is connected to the Internet and I also get messages from contacts who have messaged me but I cannot get past the initializing screen whatsoever.

Wrote to the WhatsApp team and their robot (I guess) replied saying try connecting to WiFi or reinstall or reboot and stuff.

I already tried everything!

Restarted,Formatted, Connected to WiFi, Edge, 3g... everything!

It actually started and I had to uninstall it because I suddenly got a message in the afternoon saying my backup file was corrupted.

And after that nothing is happening!!!!

What should I do now? The WhatsApp management is as it is lousy and useless. I had written to them earlier too once but they never reply!

What do I do?

I use a Micromax a52 Android 2.3.6 phone

### EDIT

Whatsapp status has tweeted that there is some problem and the system is down and that they are working on it....

I had mailed them 4 times and also gave them some screenshots and also the link to this page and also tweeted to whatsapp about the problem...so it seems  the problem has been concidered and is being worked uppon! lets wait and see now

Comment: @Suraj Bajaj..Yes I did it! cleared the cache...formated the memory card...reinstalled...even factory reset the fone...downloaded the apk from their site instead of playstore..everything! from the 2 answers below it seems like there is some problem with the app...but the only question is,how can such an error come up without any official update? are there backdoors in wapp?

Comment: sorry its 2.3.6!